# NPM install error on Linux Mint

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

Hi I have followed the steps to install node and npm on my machine but, npm install doesnt works

Here is the error log.

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'install', 'node-gyp' ]
2 info using npm@5.7.1
3 info using node@v4.8.7
4 verbose config Skipping project config: /home/manish/.npmrc. (matches userconfig)
5 verbose stack Error: Cannot find module 'node-gyp/bin/node-gyp'
5 verbose stack     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
5 verbose stack     at resolveFileName (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node_modules/resolve-from/index.js:29:39)
5 verbose stack     at resolveFrom (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node_modules/resolve-from/index.js:43:9)
5 verbose stack     at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node_modules/resolve-from/index.js:46:41)
5 verbose stack     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:18:31)
5 verbose stack     at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
5 verbose stack     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
5 verbose stack     at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
5 verbose stack     at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
5 verbose stack     at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
5 verbose stack     at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
5 verbose stack     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:4:19)
5 verbose stack     at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
5 verbose stack     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
5 verbose stack     at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
5 verbose stack     at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
6 verbose cwd /home/manish
7 verbose Linux 3.13.0-24-generic
8 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "node-gyp"
9 verbose node v4.8.7
10 verbose npm  v5.7.1
11 error code MODULE_NOT_FOUND
12 error Cannot find module 'node-gyp/bin/node-gyp'
13 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I have tried, re installing also. Can anybody please help